# Not hitting success event on AJAX call In asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am trying to bind Drop down from services. But success event is not hitting.

Science I have total 5000 records so in

**web.config** file I have added Binding May be due to this region I am getting "Internal server Error" ? I am not sure about this Please guide me where I am doing wrong

**AJAX**

```
var AllProduct = [];
        function GetAllProduct() {
            var params = { DivisionCode: $('#ddlDivision').val() };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                url: 'Header.aspx/GetProduct',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    Product(res.d)
                    OnSuccessProductCall();

                }
            });
            function Product(pdata) {
                AllProduct = pdata;
            }
        }
        function OnSuccessProductCall(data, status) {
            result = AllProduct;
            $("[id$='ddlProduct']").append($("<option>").val("0").text("Select"));
            if (result != undefined && result.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    $("[id$='ddlProduct']").append($("<option>").val($.trim(result[i].BU_CAT_CODE)).text($.trim(result[i].BU_CAT_DESC)));
                }
            }
        }
```

**Services**

While debugging I can see my services returning Collection of data But not able to hit Success Event

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static ServiceReference1.PRODUCT[] GetProduct(string DivisionCode)
        {
            ServiceReference1.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new ServiceReference1.MasterDataServiceClient();
            ServiceReference1.PRODUCT[] prod = oClient.GetProducts(DivisionCode, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            return prod;
        }
```

**Web.Cofig**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
               maxArrayLength="200000000"
               maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMasterDataService" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://almhosrwfebpm01.almaraigroup.local:8524/AlmaraiDataService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="ServiceReference1.IMasterDataService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMasterDataService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My data type is `JSON`

Sample data Coming from Web Services.

[image]
Where I am doing wrong.

**Error Message**

```
 {"Message":"An attempt was made to call the method \u0027GetProduct\u0027 using a POST request, which is not allowed.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

[image]

Comment: add `error: function (request, status, error) { alert(request.responseText); }` after success and lets see what going on.

Comment: As above, also check the browser network tab to see exactly what's being returned via your ajax call

Comment: I am getting this message {"Message":"An attempt was made to call the method \u0027GetProduct\u0027 using a GET request, which is not allowed.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: @freedomn-m as I can see network tab nothing is visible

Comment: @PakawatSmutkun I have posted In comment section message on  Error Event

Comment: do you get any error in browser console?

Comment: did you get any alert after adding Pakawat Smutkun sample code?

Comment: but my guess is this line type: 'GET', in ajax call changet to type: 'POST' @user14304386

Comment: @AlirezaMadad yes I have posted Error Message in Comment section. I have Change from GET to POST. But again its showing error Like {"Message":"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.","StackTrace":"

Comment: @AlirezaMadad I have changed from GET to POST But still error. Not hitting on success Event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Technically, you must always include an `error` event so you know when an ajax call fails and handle it accordingly. It is clearly a bad practice to ignore it.

Secondly, as far as I know, a `WebMethod` doesn't allow a `GET` request, you must use a `POST` request so it responds back and sends the data without error, or if you strictly want to use `WebMethod` in a `GET` request then you should decorate your `WebMethod` with this attribute: `[ScriptMethod (UseHttpGet = true)]`

Here is the refined `ajax` call, Try this and see what error pops up and try to resolve it again.

```
var AllProduct = [];
function GetAllProduct() {
    var params = { DivisionCode: $('#ddlDivision').val() };
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // Modified this to a POST call
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            url: 'Header.aspx/GetProduct',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (res) {
                Product(res.d)
                OnSuccessProductCall();
            },
            error: function(err) { // Added this event to capture the failed requests.
                console.log(err);
            }
   }); 
   // ... Your Further Code ...
}
```

Comment: I have changed my code yo suggested But I am getting error on console tab Like : POST http://localhost:26097/Header.aspx/GetProduct 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: This is a server error, I would recommend you to go to network tab and see if you are hitting on the correct endpoint and if the data being passed is fine.

Comment: Please check my Updated code I have posted Network tab i bilevel every thing is ok as i am getting 200 i.e. OK

Comment: Try using it in a `GET` request as in the error message it seems your service method is forcing it to use a `GET` request. Then see what the error comes.

Comment: I have change from POST to GET but still same error 500 Internal server error

Comment: Put a break point on the `WebMethod` and see if your method is being triggered or not.

Comment: i check and its hitting the break point and also returning data

Comment: It is hitting the endpoint using the ajax call or the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Add this instead of `[WebMethod]`

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public static ServiceReference1.PRODUCT[] GetProduct(string DivisionCode)
        {
            ServiceReference1.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new ServiceReference1.MasterDataServiceClient();
            ServiceReference1.PRODUCT[] prod = oClient.GetProducts(DivisionCode, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            return prod;
        }
```

[An attempt was made to call the method \u0027GetNextImage\u0027 using a GET request, which is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339929/an-attempt-was-made-to-call-the-method-u0027getnextimage-u0027-using-a-get-requ/32947550)

Comment: I have change  from  type: 'POST', to  type: 'GET',

Comment: @user14304386 if you changed to 'GET' but still get error about using 'POST' try ctrl+f5 to clear cache.

Comment: @user14304386 try adding break point on controller to see it is hit or not

Comment: @AlirezaMadad error I am getting Please check my updated Code

Comment: @PakawatSmutkun I tried using your mention code but i am getting 500 Internal server error

Answer (score 0):

change the " data: JSON.stringify(params),"
Try this:

```
data: "{obj:" + JSON.stringify(params ) + "}",
```

In the web method:
1-change the return type to void.
2-Add this code :

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(prod));
```

this article should help:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-retrieve-data-using-ajax-in-asp-net

Comment: I have Replace data: "{obj:" + JSON.stringify(params ) + "}",                                            
  But still not hitting Sucess Event As error I am getting like this:   {"Message":"An attempt was made to call the method \u0027GetProduct\u0027 using a POST request, which is not allowed.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}